# How to change weight in loss function without affecting the back propagation?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a ground truth tensor with zeros and integers, I want to change the weight by multiplying the nonzero values by 5 in the loss function, but it will affect the back propagation and causes error, Is there any other way I can achieve this in the Loss function?

```
def MSE(output,truth,batch_size):
   for i in range(batch_size):
    for pos,j in enumerate(truth[i]):
        if j != 0:
            output[i][pos] = output[i][pos]*5


   mse = ((truth.sub(output))**2).mean()
   return mse
```

Traning sections below

```
for epoch in range(EPOCH):
        losses = []
        for step,(im,pointlist) in enumerate(train_loader):

            im = im.to(device)
            output = cnn(im)
            y = torch.stack(pointlist,dim=1)
            y = y.type(torch.FloatTensor)
            y = y.to(device)
            loss = MSE(output,y,batch_size)
            optimizer.zero_grad()           
            loss.backward()                 # backpropagation, compute gradients
            optimizer.step()

            losses.append(loss.item())
        scheduler.step()
        print("Epoch={0},Loss={1:.6F}".format(epoch, np.average(np.array(losses))))
```

The error occurred at loss.backward()

```py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "CNN_Icarus.py", line 213, in <module>
        main()
    File "CNN_Icarus.py", line 203, in main
    loss.backward()# backpropagation, compute gradients
    File "C:\Users\et302\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\torch\tensor.py", line 166, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
    File "C:\Users\et302\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\__init__.py", line 99, in backward
    allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag

RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.cuda.FloatTensor [4, 20]], which is output 0 of SigmoidBackward, is at version 54; expected version 0 instead. Hint: enable anomaly detection to find the operation that failed to compute its gradient, with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True).
```

Comment: what is the error are you getting? can you put it here?

Comment: @Jpro please do not post screenshots - search engines cannot index them. Just copy-paste the error message and the trace.

Comment: @Jpro try [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/encounter-the-runtimeerror-one-of-the-variables-needed-for-gradient-computation-has-been-modified-by-an-inplace-operation/836/3) solution. Get `.clone()` first on which you want to apply operations.